# Retrieve all records for a single CustomMetaDataType using ant

Tags: ant, migration-tool, custom-metadata

I'm trying to use the ant migration tool to retrieve all the Custom Metadata records for a single `Custom Metadata Type`.  However, I can't figure out the syntax.

I would think that something like this would work:

```
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>State_Sales_Tax.*</members>
        <name>CustomMetadata</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>State_Sales_Tax__mdt</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <version>36.0</version>
</Package>
```

but no dice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you would be able to do something like that.
You either use a wild card character or mention the names of the individual elements directly.

Something like this.

```
<types>
    <members>State_Sales_Tax_1</members>
    <members>State_Sales_Tax_2</members>
    <members>State_Sales_Tax_3</members>
    <name>CustomMetadata</name>
</types>
```

(or)

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>CustomMetadata</name>
</types>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the package.xml to retrieve all the custom metadata

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
 <types>
<members>*</members>
<name>CustomMetadata</name>
 </types>
 <version>37.0</version>
 </Package>
```

You can specify the name to retrieve an individual

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
 <types>
<members>test1</members>
<name>CustomMetadata</name>
 </types>
 <version>37.0</version>
 </Package>
```

Comment: Anyway to retrieve the custom metadata type records using sfdx? When I used
<members>*</members>
<name>CustomMetadata</name>
with the sfdx force:source:retrieve command I get the error "The specified metadata type is unsupported"

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't possible using wildcards within a package.xml, you can do this with the metadata api by first doing a list call to retrieve all custom metadata types. From there you can filter down to your specific custom metadata type and build a package.xml for a retrieve call.

Answer (score 0):

To Retrieve a Custom Metadata Records of Specific Custom MetaData Records.
Here's what I did
1)

1. Simple SOQL to get Developer Name of the CM records
2. Pasted the results in Excel and appended

   membersTAG NameoftheCMObject(excluding __mdt).DeveloperName of the
   CM Records
   membersTAG
3. Removed other members tags which retrieves other SF Org Data like
   Apex Classes etc in package.xml
4. So My package XML only contains
   <xml......

   CM.DeveloperNames(We simply paste the result
   of exercise in excel)
   .
   .
   .
   .
   CustomMetadata
5. BOOM Just press Retreive source from ORG and DONE

Answer (score 0):

For most cases, I'd suggest this approach, with no need for `package.xml`.

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomMetadata:State_Sales_Tax.*
```