# Retrieve all Custom Metadata for a single type

Tags: metadata-api, metadata, custom-metadata

Is it possible to somehow retrieve all metadata for a single custom metadata type via `ant` or `sfdx mdapi` ?

I've tried this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Env_Var__mdt.*</members>
        <name>CustomMetadata</name>
    </types>
    <version>45.0</version>
</Package>
```

but it doesn't work...

I know I can get EVERYTHING with `<members>*</members>` but that's not really helpful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not possible(As of summer 2019 release).The reason for that is salesforce does not recognize custom metadata records are dependent on the custom metadata Object.

I tried to create an unmanaged package container and add custom metadata object and see if there is any dependency that it auto adds records.Hence I think this should be opened on Ideaexchange as product enhancement.

Comment: i thought I had done a similar thing with changeset and it did pick them up as dependent, but I could be mistaken

Comment: I doubt it picks up if you add custom metadata object and then check dependency .

Comment: just tried it. You're correct....

Even without the dep, it would be nice if SF allowed you to do more robust wildcards in `package.xml`

Comment: Agree .We should create an idea and socialize on Twitter to get traction

Comment: Not much changed since last time :P https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/137778/retrieve-all-records-for-a-single-custommetadatatype-using-ant

Comment: Huh !! Did not realize there is same question being asked long before .

Comment: I'm not sure how much search didn't turn that up.  Voted to close as duplicate

Comment: I just realized the DUPLICATE is my question as well... LOL how embarrassing

Comment: It absolutely is possible with no need for `package.xml`.  `sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomMetadata:Env_Var__mdt.*`